# Making a server module for reuse in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to put the following code (except the socket module and `io` function) into a separate js file for reuse.

`index.js`

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
http = require('http').createServer(app), 
url = require('url'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
io = require("socket.io").listen(http),  // question with this line

app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){
  key = req.cookies["phpsession"];
  var filename = req.param("tagId");
  res.sendfile(filename+'.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

//..Other code....//

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Here's my attempt following this [guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/):

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(), 
http = require('http').createServer(app), 
url = require('url'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),

module.exports = {
 express_app : function(){

  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res){
   key = req.cookies["phpsession"];
   var filename = req.param("tagId");
   res.sendfile(compare+filename+'.html');
  });
 },

 server_http: function(port){
  http.listen(port, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:'+port);
  });
 }
}
```

`index.js`

```
  var server = require('./server');
  server.express_app();
  server.server_http(3000);
  var io = require("socket.io").listen(server.server_http(3000));
  io.on('connection', function(socket){......
```

Is that the appropriate way of creating and exporting the module? What I'm not sure is this line in the new index.js:

```
  server.server_http(3000);
  var io = require("socket.io").listen(server.server_http(3000));
```

It seems like I'm invoking `http.listen` twice, the console.log gives me duplicated `listening on *:3000` as soon as I run the server.Can you give me some suggestions on how to change the server.js.

Comment: Not quite how I would do it, but why not put the io setup inside server.js as well? You could expose it as `server.socket_io`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your socket.io problem.

In Server.js :

```
server_http: function(port, callback){
  http.listen(port, function(){
   callback(this); // this = server instance
   console.log('listening on *:'+port);
  });
}
```

index.js :

```
server.server_http(3000, function (server) {
  var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
  io.on('connection', function(socket){......
});
```